# Android- Set time on TimePicker from SharedPrefs ints

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, timepicker, android-sharedpreferences

I have a TimePicker set in the 24 hour format. I have tried something like this in the onCreate() method of my activity class that uses it, but it doesn't seem to keep the time I change when I back out and reload the activity. Is something wrong with this? Do I need to "submit" the time, if so how?

```
final TimePicker t = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    t.setIs24HourView(true);
    t.setHour(prefs.getInt("hour",15));
    t.setMinute(prefs.getInt("min",15));
    t.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            editor.putInt("hour",hourOfDay);
            editor.putInt("min",minute);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this- editor.commit()?

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! I just knew it would be something simple! I'll accept when it lets me.

Comment: @CarsonChild cheers!! please accept the answer if it helped you.